# Why does object dtype array contain datetime.datetime objects instead of numpy.datetime64 objects?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, datetime

I do not understand why my numpy array is storing the `numpy.datetime64` values in `dts` as `datetime.datetime` objects.

```py
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: import datetime
In [3]: arr = np.ones((3,), dtype='O') 
In [4]: dts = np.array([np.datetime64(datetime.datetime.today())] * 2)
In [5]: dts
Out[5]: 
array(['2020-08-20T14:44:03.945058', '2020-08-20T14:44:03.945058'],
      dtype='datetime64[us]')
In [6]: arr[:2] = dts 
In [7]: arr                                                                     
Out[7]: 
array([datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 20, 14, 44, 3, 945058),
       datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 20, 14, 44, 3, 945058), 1], dtype=object)
```

I have been able to work around this using the code below, but my actual case is more complex and I would much rather use the approach above.

```
In [8]: arr = np.ones((3,), dtype='O')  
In [9]: dts = np.array([np.datetime64(datetime.datetime.today())] * 2) 
In [10]: for i in [0, 1]: 
    ...:     arr[i] = dts[i]  
In [11]: arr                                                                    
Out[11]: 
array([numpy.datetime64('2020-08-20T14:53:20.878553'),
       numpy.datetime64('2020-08-20T14:53:20.878553'), 1], dtype=object)
```

Why does the first approach not store the exact object type from `dts` given `arr` is `object` dtype?

Comment: You sort of asked it to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [346]: dts = np.array([np.datetime64(datetime.datetime.today())] * 2)                             
In [347]: dts                                                                                        
Out[347]: 
array(['2020-08-20T14:46:12.940815', '2020-08-20T14:46:12.940815'],
      dtype='datetime64[us]')
```

`tolist` converts the array to a list, rendering elements as base Python objects where possible - evidently `datatime64` is programmed to render itself as `datetime` objects:

```
In [348]: dts.tolist()                                                                               
Out[348]: 
[datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 20, 14, 46, 12, 940815),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 20, 14, 46, 12, 940815)]
```

Converting the `dts` array to object type also converts the elements to `datetime`:

```
In [387]: dts.astype(object)[0]                                                                      
Out[387]: datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 20, 14, 46, 12, 940815)
```

So the `arr[:]= dts`, must be going through either `tolist` or `astype(object)`.

```
In [349]: dts[0]                                                                                     
Out[349]: numpy.datetime64('2020-08-20T14:46:12.940815')
In [350]: arr = np.ones(2, object)                                                                   
In [351]: arr[:] = dts                                                                               
In [352]: arr                                                                                        
Out[352]: 
array([datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 20, 14, 46, 12, 940815),
       datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 20, 14, 46, 12, 940815)], dtype=object)
```

Something similar happens with floats:

```
In [360]: x = np.array([1.23, 23.2])                                                                 
In [361]: type(x[0])                                                                                 
Out[361]: numpy.float64
In [362]: arr[:] = x                                                                                 
In [363]: arr                                                                                        
Out[363]: array([1.23, 23.2], dtype=object)
In [364]: type(arr[0])                                                                               
Out[364]: float
```

Assigning a single item preserves the dtype:

```
In [365]: arr[0] = x[0]                                                                              
In [366]: arr                                                                                        
Out[366]: array([1.23, 23.2], dtype=object)
In [367]: type(arr[0])                                                                               
Out[367]: numpy.float64
In [368]: type(arr[1])                                                                               
Out[368]: float
```

`arr` now contains a `np.float64` and a `float`.

Keep in mind that an object dtype array stores references to objects - objects which are elsewhere in memory.  In that regard it's a lot like a list.  On the other hand a numeric dtype array stores bytes, which are interpreted by the `dtype` mechanism.  `dts[0]` does not actually reference a 8 byte block of `dts`; it's a new `datetime64` object. And `arr[0]` (in the above code) is another `datetime64` object (with the same value).

Comment: Is there any way that you can think of to avoid a `for` loop to get the result I'm looking for?

Comment: @dshanahan Is there a reason you have to use `dtype='O'`? Could you use a structured array instead, with real numpy datetime64 for the first 2 columns?